# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target in spring rest template client

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, ssl

I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException

for the following program:

```
private static String       url    = "https://localhost:8080/ipn";
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add( "Accept", "application/json" );
    headers.setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) requestFactory.getHttpClient();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate( requestFactory );
    requestChange( headers, restTemplate );
}

private static void requestChange( HttpHeaders inHeaders, RestTemplate inRestTemplate )
{
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put( "PresentmentCurrencyCode", "INR" );
    params.put( "SettlementCurrencyCode", "INR" );
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>( inHeaders );
    ResponseEntity<String> response = inRestTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class, params );
    System.out.println( response.toString() );
}
```

I am getting the following error while access the `url` in spring rest template client.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://xmlservice-stg03extf.symantec.com/SymWalletServices/PayPalListner/ipn":sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:503)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:408)
at com.np.symantec.ChargeBackClient.requestChargeBack(ChargeBackClient.java:94)
at com.np.symantec.ChargeBackClient.main(ChargeBackClient.java:74)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:543)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:88)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
... 4 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 31 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your client does not trust the resource you are calling. You will have to import the public key of your target resource

Answer (score 0):

There may be typo error for **localhost** spelling

Try changing it as below:

private static String       url    = "https://localhost:8080/ipn";

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have set an SSL context anywhere, so your app doesn't know how to validate the https connection you've made.

You need to set it when you initialise your httpClient, for example:

```
socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```